# Pushing Extended Widget Flutter

Tags: flutter, scroll, widget

Here is the app code , problem is when keyboard is shown TextField is pushed , but it covers  Extended widget , what can be done so it also "pushes" Extended above AppBar?

Note , here in this example I purposely disabled resizeToAvoidBottom insets , as that is implemented with sized box , with that it turned to true , it simple creates empty space.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List<int> data = List.generate(50, (index) => index);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
        extendBody: true,
        extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
        body: Column(
          children: [
            // SizedBox(
            //   height: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom,
            // ),
            Expanded(
              child: ListView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemCount: data.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) => ListTile(
                  title: Center(child: Text(data[index].toString())),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            TextFormField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(border: OutlineInputBorder()),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom,
            )
          ],
        ));
  }
}
```

Edit #1
Added gif demo[image: Demo]

Answer (score 0):

Because the TextFormField wasn't in a scrollable (ex: ListView, SingleChildScrollView, ...) so it won't be scrolled automatically when it had focus. So the solution is adding the TextFormField in a scrollable widget.

This is my code, it worked well, i also edited your code so it will be shorter ;) :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List<int> data = List.generate(50, (index) => index);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
        // extendBody: true,
        // extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
        body: ListView.builder(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemCount: data.length + 1,
          itemBuilder: (context, index)  {
            if(index ==50){
              return TextFormField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(border: OutlineInputBorder()),
              );
            }
          return ListTile(
          title: Center(child: Text(data[index].toString())),
          );
          }
        ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This renders input at the bottom which is not what I want , it needs to **stick** at the bottom , anyway you did help me by indicating on **SingleChildScrollView** , so thanks.